# Package conflict between regexpatch and newpxtext

Tags: packages, incompatibility, xpatch

The new version of `newpxtext` seems to load `xpatch`, which would conflict with packages that use `regexpatch`. Is there some way to fix this? For example, is it possible to prevent `xpatch` from being loaded when `regexpatch` has already been loaded?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage { regexpatch }
\RequirePackage { newpxtext }

\begin{document}
Text in case of empty.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should always keep in mind that `regexpatch` is experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I'm not sure `newpx` ought to be patching really but anyway you can do this

```
\documentclass{article}


\RequirePackage { regexpatch }
\expandafter\let\csname ver@xpatch.sty\endcsname\empty
\RequirePackage { newpxtext }

\begin{document}
Text in case of empty.
\end{document}
```

Perhaps regexpatch should always suppress xpatch in this way (and emulate its commands) I'm not sure..

Comment: where's @egreg ....

Comment: Thank you for this! May I ask if there is much difference with `\@namedef{ver@xpatch.sty}{}`?

Comment: @Jinwen no difference at all except you would need `\makeatletter` to use `\@namedef` in the preamble

Comment: The newpx patch looks wrong, it simply activates old style numbers and that can affect following font shapes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, but egreg could make `\usepackage{regexpatch,xpatch}` not error even if newpx didn't patch at all.